# Python: generate list by mapping fields of another data

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python3.x, I have code which generates X with list of sub-lists in single quotes separated by comma, and my task is to map some of 'X' fields to 'Y' sample list, output of 'Y' is multiplied by number of lines in "X"

```
X = 
[
'sequence:1, MAP:A, num1:1, num2:2, num3:3', 
'sequence:2, num1:10, num2:20, MAP:B, num3:30',
'sequence:3, num1:100, MAP:C, num2:200, num3:300'
]

Y = ['VEQ','1','MAP-replacehere','2','num1-replacehere',]
```

required output:

```
'VEQ','1','A','2','1'      ##col3,5 replaced from MAP:A and num1:1
'VEQ','1','B','2','10'     ##col3,5 replaced from MAP:B and num1:10
'VEQ','1','C','2','100'    ##col3,5 replaced from MAP:C and num1:100
```

(Other fields of 'Y' remained same and only col3,5 are mapped from 'X')

To describe above output,

I have generated 'Y' sample lines for 3 times, because X has 3 lines.

I have replaced 'Y' column-3 with dict field of "MAP" from "X" (column number is not fixed for MAP inside 'X'. It could in column1, or 2, or 3 so on..)

I have replaced 'Y' column-5 with dict field of 'num1' from "X" (column number is not fixed for num1 inside 'X')**

**What I have tried:**
I have below an example, that works with X sample, which is not in dict format.. and column fields are fixed..

```
X = ['sequence, A, 1, 2, 3', 
     'sequence, B, 10, 20, 30', 
     'sequence, C, 100, 200, 300']

Y = ['VEQ','1','map','2','cap',]

def replace(X,Y,position_list):
    result = []
    for x in X:
        x = x.split(',')
        x = [t.strip() for t in x]
        temp = Y.copy()
        for pos in position_list:
            temp[pos[0] - 1] = x[pos[1] - 1]
        result.append(temp)
    return result

replace(X,Y,[(3,2),(5,3)]) #####this is working for fixed columns of X.
```

Could you please help, if this code can be modified to get desired result, or else if any other method can achieve this..

thanks in advance..

Comment: The above dict is not a valid `dictionary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my approach to this problem.

```
X =['sequence:1, MAP:A, num1:1, num2:2, num3:3',
'sequence:2, num1:10, num2:20, MAP:B, num3:30',
'sequence:3, num1:100, MAP:C, num2:200, num3:300']


Y = []

for val in X:
    map_replace = str(val).split('MAP:')[1].split(',')[0].strip()
    num1_replace = str(val).split('num1:')[1].split(',')[0].strip()
    Y.append(['VEQ','1',map_replace,'2',num1_replace])

print(Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first convert every line from X to a dictionary. This must be done *by hand* because what you have is neither valid json nor even *eval*-able strings.

Then for each field from X, if the value ends with `-replacehere` you replace it with the value of the prefix in the dictionary built from the row from X.

As a Python function, it could look like:

```
import re

X = [
'sequence:1, MAP:A, num1:1, num2:2, num3:3', 
'sequence:2, num1:10, num2:20, MAP:B, num3:30',
'sequence:3, num1:100, MAP:C, num2:200, num3:300'
]

Y = ['VEQ','1','MAP-replacehere','2','num1-replacehere',]

def replace(x, y):
    # prepare splitting of rows from X
    splitter = re.compile(r'\s*,\s*')

    #prepare Y processing
    rep = '-replacehere'
    length = len(rep)

    y2 = [(i[:-length], True) if  i.endswith(rep) else (i, False)
          for i in y]
    # with the example Y it gives [('VEQ', False), ('1', False), ('MAP', True), 
    #                              ('2', False), ('num1', True)]

    # run...
    for line in X:
        d = { m[0]: m[1] for m in [
            item.split(':', 1) for item in splitter.split(line)]}
        print(*[repr(d[i[0]] if i[1] else i[0]) for i in y2])
```

You can then call the function:

```
>>> replace(X, Y)
'VEQ' '1' 'A' '2' '1'
'VEQ' '1' 'B' '2' '10'
'VEQ' '1' 'C' '2' '100'
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your help.. your suggestion works.. but only concern is i am getting "none" at end of output.. which i dont understand...